What are the differences of Scalar and Pseudoscalar Yukawa Theory?
I know that some polarized interactions are forbidden.
But for unpolarized (summed over incoming and outgoing spins), are the amplitudes and decay rates of a Yukawa scalar and pseudoscalar coupled to one fermion identical? I'm new to QFT so maybe I just made some mistakes calculating these amplitudes...
Are there some observable differences in unpolarized interactions? Maybe with a symmetry breaking mechanism associated to the scalar potential?

Read  this?
